# Does the definition of countable ordinals require the power set axiom?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to understand the consequences of the different axioms of ZFC. In particular, I was trying to understand what you get on ZFC-power set (ZFC minus the power set axiom). If you have any references that I could read please let me know. In particular, I have a question. From the definition of ordinal number (for instance, Jech, p.19 and above) I believe that you do not need the power set axiom to define infinite ordinals beyond $\omega$, but I am not completely sure. If you don't need it, which is the largest ordinal that you can reach without using power set? can you reach $\omega_1$?

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778/uncountable-ordinals-without-power-set-axiom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be very interested in the following paper:

> Victoria Gitman, Joel David Hamkins, Thomas A. Johnstone, [**What is the theory ZFC without power set?**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2430) (arXiv, 2011)

Note that you cannot prove the existence of $\omega_1$ either, this is because $H(\omega_1)$, the set of the hereditarily countable sets contain all the countable ordinals, and it is a model of $\sf ZFC-Pwr$, but $\omega_1\notin H(\omega_1)$ because it is not hereditarily countable.